# Slashes in json returned from node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am getting slashes in the json returned from Node server. This is giving challenges in parsing the json.

The json looks like

```
"{\"responseCode\":200,\"headers\":{\"Access-Control-Allow-Origin\":\"*\",\"Content-Type\":\"application/json; charset=utf-8\",\"X-Powered-By\":\"Express\",\"Connection\":\"keep-alive\",\"Date\":\"Thu, 22 Sep 2016 08:12:39 GMT\",\"Content-Length\":\"21\",\"Etag\":\"W/\\"15-HeifZ4bmt+WxpIWDoartGQ\\"\"},\"response\":\"{\\"status\\":\\"UP\\"}\",\"bytesSent\":715779}"
```

In order to get rid of the slashes, I did a replace and then converted it back to json using JSON.parse

```
.then(function (result) {
     var status = "";
     var str = JSON.stringify(result); 
     console.log("str result  ", str);
     str = str.replace(/\\/g, "");
     console.log("result after cleanup  ", str);
     var obj = JSON.parse(str);
     status = obj.response.status;
}
```

After replacing the slashes, the string looks like this

```
"{\"responseCode\":200,\"headers\":{\"Access-Control-Allow-Origin\":\"*\",\"Content-Type\":\"application/json; charset=utf-8\",\"X-Powered-By\":\"Express\",\"Connection\":\"keep-alive\",\"Date\":\"Thu, 22 Sep 2016 08:12:39 GMT\",\"Content-Length\":\"21\",\"Etag\":\"W/\"15-HeifZ4bmt+WxpIWDoartGQ\"\"},\"response\":\"{\"status\":\"UPLOADED\"}\",\"bytesSent\":715779}"
```

When I try to parse it to JSON object, it throws an error on

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

It seems that the JSON is still invalid due to the slashes which still exist.

I have the following queries -

1. How can I update my regex to get rid of these slashes as well
2. Why do these slashes get introduced in the response

Comment: Are you also developing the serverside node server? This seems like a problem on that side.

Comment: Is that the _actual_ string, or just the representation of it?  How are you viewing it?  If it really is outputting it with the quotes escaped like that, the best solution is to go fix whatever is generating the JSON so it's valid, rather than trying to parse invalid stuff.

Comment: I am viewing it in the browser console. Don't have much control over the node side as it is already there and being used by other apps. So, need to find a workaround on the client side to get moving.

Comment: It the actual and the complete string

Comment: Could you post the node.js code? Thats where the problem is

Comment: `JSON.parse({{YOUR SLASHED RESULT}})`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is the method used to **generate** a JSON string. If you apply it to something that's already a JSON string then you'll get a double-encoded JSON string:

```
var alreadyJson = '{"foo": "bar"}';
var doubleEncoded = JSON.stringify(alreadyJson);
console.log(doubleEncoded , typeof doubleEncoded);
```

```js
"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}" string
```

What you need to use is the [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method:

```
var alreadyJson = '{"foo": "bar"}';
var decoded = JSON.parse(alreadyJson);
console.log(decode, typeof decoded);
```

```
{ foo: 'bar' } 'object'
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regx to eliminate slashes.

```
var response = '{\"responseCode\":200,\"headers\":{\"Access-Control-Allow-Origin\":\"*\",\"Content-Type\":\"application/json; charset=utf-8\",\"X-Powered-By\":\"Express\",\"Connection\":\"keep-alive\",\"Date\":\"Thu, 22 Sep 2016 08:12:39 GMT\",\"Content-Length\":\"21\",\"Etag\":\"W/\\"15-HeifZ4bmt+WxpIWDoartGQ\\"\"},\"response\":\"{\\"status\\":\\"UP\\"}\",\"bytesSent\":715779}';
JSON.parse(response);
```

This will give you JSON object eliminating slashes.
[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 1):

If I put some newlines in your string, it looks like this:

```
"{
  \"responseCode\":200,
  \"headers\":{
    \"Access-Control-Allow-Origin\":\"*\",
    \"Content-Type\":\"application/json; charset=utf-8\",
    \"X-Powered-By\":\"Express\",
    \"Connection\":\"keep-alive\",
    \"Date\":\"Thu, 22 Sep 2016 08:12:39 GMT\",
    \"Content-Length\":\"21\",
    \"Etag\":\"W/\\"15-HeifZ4bmt+WxpIWDoartGQ\\"\"
  },
  \"response\":\"{\\"status\\":\\"UP\\"}\",
  \"bytesSent\":715779
}"
```

We can see that one of the issue is at line `Etag`. The part `\\"15` should be `\\\"15`. One backslash to espace the next backslash, then again a backslash to espace the quote.

It's the same issue for `status` and `UP`. Fix your server :)

Comment: Actually, even StackOverflow syntax highlighting tells you that the issue is at Etag.