# node-mysql JSON type returned quoted with backslash

Tags: mysql, sql, json, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to fetch JSON type data from Mysql in Node.js application via node-mysql module.

running this query **on the DB**:

```
SELECT countries.id,
   countries.country_name,
   Json_object("start", start_port, "end", end_port)
   ten_minutes,
   Json_object("start", start_port + 10000, "end", end_port + 10000)
   one_minutes,
   Json_object("start", start_port + 20000, "end", end_port + 20000)
   thirty_minutes
FROM   countries
   JOIN countries_port_ranges
     ON country_id = countries.id;
```

return:

```
1   Afghanistan {"start": 8000, "end": 8029}    {"start": 18000, "end": 18029}  {"start": 28000, "end": 28029}
2   Albania {"start": 8030, "end": 8059}    {"start": 18030, "end": 18059}  {"start": 28030, "end": 28059}
3   Algeria {"start": 8060, "end": 8089}    {"start": 18060, "end": 18089}  {"start": 28060, "end": 28089}
```

when I'm running this query via node-mysql or Sequelize I get this result:

```
 [{
    "id": 1,
    "country_name": "Afghanistan",
    "ten_minutes": "{\"start\": 8000, \"end\": 8029}",
    "one_minutes": "{\"start\": 18000, \"end\": 18029}",
    "thirty_minutes": "{\"start\": 28000, \"end\": 28029}"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "country_name": "Albania",
    "ten_minutes": "{\"start\": 8030, \"end\": 8059}",
    "one_minutes": "{\"start\": 18030, \"end\": 18059}",
    "thirty_minutes": "{\"start\": 28030, \"end\": 28059}"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "country_name": "Algeria",
    "ten_minutes": "{\"start\": 8060, \"end\": 8089}",
    "one_minutes": "{\"start\": 18060, \"end\": 18089}",
    "thirty_minutes": "{\"start\": 28060, \"end\": 28089}"
}]
```

app.js:

```
async (req, res) => {
    const q = `SELECT...`
    const query = await sequelize.query(q, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
    res.send(query)
}
```

My question is- How can I get pure JSON (without the backslash) and not as escaped string ?

**expected:**

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "country_name": "Algeria",
    "ten_minutes": {"start": 8060, "end": 8089},
    "one_minutes": {"start": 18060, "end": 18089},
    "thirty_minutes": {"start": 28060, "end": 28089}
}
```

** Avoid editing the return data again (by running some map function..)

Thanks.

Comment: try res.send(query.toJson())

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: Please look at this question. It might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634035/slashes-in-json-returned-from-node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the link provided by @vedran-maricevic -

The reason it happen is because node-mysql pass the data rows as json and it includes a json rows inside and -

> if you apply JSON.stringify() to something that's already a json
>   string then you'll get a double-encoded json string.

Applying JSON.parse() on each json object won't work and will throw error cause its already a json object.

So quick and dirty solution is to apply JSON.parse() on the double-encoded fields only:

```
const _parsed = query.map(obj => {
        const tmp = {}
        tmp.id = obj.id
        tmp.country_name = obj.country_name
        tmp.ten_minutes = JSON.parse(obj.ten_minutes) // double-encoded field
        tmp.one_minutes = JSON.parse(obj.one_minutes) // double-encoded field
        tmp.thirty_minutes = JSON.parse(obj.thirty_minutes) // double-encoded field
        return tmp
    })
    res.send(parsed)
```

Hope it will help someone :)